# How to set Image fit to screen as wallpaper in devices?

Tags: java, android, screen, android-wallpaper

I want to Set Image viewed in app as wallpaper.

While trying to do so image doesn't fit to screen of my device but its viewed properly using centerCrop.

This is my Code for the app.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="Set Wallpaper"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setWallpaper();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setWallpaper(){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This is image used in App

[image: Image used for the app]

Live App Screen

[image: Running App Screen Live View]

After Setting Wallpaper in android Device

[image: Set wallpaper]

How can I set image as wallpaper perfectly as used in XML file (scale to centerCrop) for setting it as perfect fit wallpaper for any android devices?

Comment: set it match parent

Comment: Tried using that but no result

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

instead of:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: I want to set that image as my smartphone background(wallpaper)